# Rpi4 as a mouse and keyboard hid with circuit python to a win10 pc

Tags: pi-4, keyboard, mouse, circuitpython, hid

0

I am looking to control a windows 10 computer with a raspberry pi4, as a mouse and keyboard. I already have the power thing handled, with a usb power blocking but data through connector. I am just looking for the code to do this.

I am looking to put coordinates in, and click on the location, then type in information received at the raspberry pi. I am hoping micropython or circuit python can do it.

Thanks,

Steve C.

Comment: this is a question and answer site ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post ... also add a description of what you tried and how the attempt did not give you the desired results